# AWSDynamoDB will not load my tables after Xcode 9 Swift 4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, swift4, xcode9

When running AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper load or query, the task.result or paginatedOutput would return an empty table. When I tried to access a property in this table, I would get an error that said: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

This started after upgrading to Xcode 9 and Swift 4. I also upgraded AWS to 2.6.1

Answer (score 0):

Turns out AWS uses class_copyPropertyList to capture the properties in your AWSDynamoDBObjectModel class. As of Swift 4, you must put @objc in front of your properties if you want it to work. Here is what worked for me:

```
import AWSDynamoDB

class Book : AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling  {
    @objc var Title:String?
    @objc var Author:String?
    @objc var Price:String?
    @objc var ISBN:String?

    class Amazon DynamoDBTableName() -> String {
        return "Books"
    }

    class func hashKeyAttribute() -> String {
        return "ISBN"
    }
}
```